# Не устанавливается Laravel UI

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

всем привет, через ftp с хостинга перенёс проект на локалку, установил аутентификацию на проект laravel, всё работает. Пробую ставить laravel UI, установил все пакеты, но по документации я должен прописать npm install && npm run dev, но выходит ошибка, как я предполагаю из-за того, что в корне проекта нет файла package.json, его действительно нет в корне проекта. Разве Laravel является nodeJs? Я не могу решить эту проблему сутки, может кто-то сталкивался, заранее благодарю!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Разве Laravel является nodeJs?` -- Laravel не является Node.js, что бы это не значило. Но Laravel использует Laravel Mix, что в свою очередь является оберткой над Webpack и использует Node.js для сборки JS модулей и фронтенд разработки соответственно.

Comment: @Simon Приветствую, спасибо за информацию, что в данной ситуации я могу предпринять?

Comment: Вам нужен собственно `package.json` этого проекта о котором Вы и говорили и очень странно что он отсутствует, так как при установке Laravel он на месте. Возможно у проекта есть GitHub репозиторий где присутствует этот файл?

Comment: @Simon к сожалению нет, вообще не знаю откуда его взять, не знаю, что можно предпринять.

Comment: @Simon Я недавно в ларавел, и хотел бы узнать, можно ли мне создать новый проект с нуля и перенести туда этот?

Comment: Тяжело сказать так как нужно знать что это за проект и исходить уже из этого, имеет ли это хоть какой-то смысл. Так-то Вы конечно можете скачать стандартный package.json из репозитория Laravel для Вашей версии, закинуть его в проект пройтись по исходникам JS и SCSS и добавить пакеты которых не хватает. Там же есть исходники?

Comment: @Simon да, исходники есть. Впервые сталкиваюсь с ларавел, плюс к этому дорабатываю проект, который делался 1.5 года назад, столько проблем, кошмар.. Спасибо за совет, удачной недели!